# How do I make Vertica timeseries, with slice_time '1 week', start on a specific day of week?

Tags: time-series, vertica

I have select like this:

```
SELECT slice_time, TS_LAST_VALUE(x) FROM table \ 
 TIMESERIES slice_time as '1 week' OVER (partition by acc_id order by updated_at)
```

The problem I have is that my first "updated_at" is on 2013-02-20 (wednesday), but the timeseries query gives me first record on 2013-02-16 (saturday). I have noticed that for any date it produces the first record in the timeseries always on saturday before the actual date.

Is there a way to make it start on a different day?

Thanks.

Comment: Set period to '7 day'?

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the very same result.

Comment: @VojtaPasler Please give us a sample data set and what the desired result should look like. You can use SQL Fiddle and select PostreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem myself. Here is how I was able to customize the start date with 10/01 being the start of the series on a random day:

```
select
    ts + datediff('dd', min(ts) over(), '2015/10/01') week_start
from
    (
    select
        ts
    from (
        select
            timestamp_trunc('2015/10/01','dd') tm
        union
        select
            timestamp_trunc('2015/10/28','dd') tm
       ) as ts
    timeseries ts as '1 Week' OVER (order by tm)
    )a
```

Answer (score 0):

Your observation that the date calculated is a Saturday is correct, and you'll need to account for that in your code.  Per the Vertica documentation [here](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/TimeSeries/TimeSeriesRounding.htm?TocPath=Analyzing%20Data%7CTime%20Series%20Analytics%7CGap%20Filling%20and%20Interpolation%20(GFI)%7C_____3), all time series of weeks start on Saturday because the baseline timestamp 2000-01-01 00:00:00 is a Saturday.